# Cordova file download not working

Tags: android, file, cordova

I have the below function to download a file to the phone,and i called this on device ready.but it call error callback every time.

```
function downloadFile(){
 var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
 fileTransfer.download(
    "http://developer.android.com/assets/images/home/ics-android.png",
    "file://sdcard/ics-android.png",
    function(entry) {
        alert("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
    },
    function(error) {
        alert("download error source " + error.source);
        alert("download error target " + error.target);
        alert("upload error code" + error.code);
    });
 }
```

I installed plugin as perthis link https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html
And my android manifest.xml have the following permitions.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: and the error message is?

Comment: @jcesarmobile alert("upload error code" + error.code); return 1

Comment: 1 is file not found, but the image url is fine, maybe the problem it's the file://sdcard/ route, are you sure it exists?

Comment: i am not sure about that path.do you know how can i specify the path ?

Comment: I use window.requestFileSystem first, it returns the fileSystem, then I convert it to url and add my folder and file name: fileSystem.root.toURL() + '/myFolder/download.jpg'

Comment: @jcesarmobile var fileSystem = window.requestFileSystem; is this correct?

Comment: No, try with the example I have posted as an answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84169/discussion-between-shijin-and-jcesarmobile).

Comment: @jcesarmobile is there any way to open the downloaded pdf file?

Comment: On iOS you can use inAppBrowser plugin with _blank param, on android you can try with _system option, and if it doesn't work you should search for a file opener plugin or app launcher or some other plugins that launch another app that can display pdfs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try requesting the file system first

```
function downloadFile(){
    var downloadUrl = "http://developer.android.com/assets/images/home/ics-android.png";
    var fileName = "ics-android.png";

    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fileSystem) {
       var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
       fileTransfer.download(
          downloadUrl,
          fileSystem.root.toURL() + '/' + fileName,

          function (entry) {
             alert("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
          },
          function (error) {
              alert("download error source " + error.source);
              alert("download error target " + error.target);
              alert("upload error code" + error.code);
          }
       );
    });
}
```